# Associate CodeCommit repo While creating Sagemaker notebook Instance

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker, aws-codecommit

I am trying to create Sagemaker notebook instance using cloudformation template. Just wanted to see if there is any way i can associate codecommit repo to that note book instance.

I know simple way to create repo and associate it using sagemaker via GUI easily.. However, is there any way we can associate via template.

I found similar info on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-git-repo.html But it doesn't show with cloudformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SageMaker now supports associating code repository including CodeCommit and any other Git repository with Notebook Instances via CloudFormation.

Here's the link for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-coderepository.html